# Why does the Python keyring package generate this warning on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-keyring

The following is what I see when I `import keyring` in Python 3 on a macOS 10.13 system:

```
# python3                                                                                                 library/repos/turf
Python 3.5.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 16:22:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keyring
dbus[2365]: Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
dbus[2365]: Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
```

My copy of the keyring package was installed using `pip`:

```
# pip3 list | grep -i keyring
keyring                            13.0.0
```

The documentation for keyring mentions the need for dbus on Linux, but does not appear to say anything about a similar requirement for macOS, yet simply importing keyring results in the message about "dbus" shown above.

Is there something I should be doing to avoid this warning message?

Comment: I've filed an issue report with the keyring project repo on GitHub: https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/334